# Identify all instances in dataframe based on the specific column value using loop

Tags: python, pandas, iteration, slice, sequence

I have the following dataframe..

```
teamId  matchId matchPeriod eventSec    eventId eventName
190 8516    5237840 1H  721.2   5   Interruption
191 8516    5237840 1H  723.4   3   Free Kick
192 8516    5237840 1H  725.7   8   Pass
193 8516    5237840 1H  727.2   8   Pass
194 8516    5237840 1H  728.5   10  Shot
```

This goes on for around 1000 rows

I would like to identify all the instances of 'Shot' and then slice out that row AND the previous 4 rows and create a sequence so I can work with the data

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:
dta # your dataframe

```
index = dta[dta['eventName'] == 'Shot'].index

result = []
for i in range(5):
    result = result + list(index - i)

result = set(result)

sub = dta[dta.index.isin(result)]
```

First it select the index of the rows with Value `'Shot'` as their column `'eventName'`. Then we create a set and iterative operations to get 4 rows previous to the selected rows.

In the end, we are selecting the rows that we have collected the index.

Answer (score -2):

Seems like you want to slice the previous four rows where "Shot" appear. You can use the index value to find where "Shot" appears and then slice the DataFrame based on the index value.

Add Data to dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
from tabulate import tabulate

dict = {
    "teamid": [190,191,192,108,190,190,191,192,108,190,190,191,192,108,190,190,191,192,108,190],
    "eventId": [5,2,4,5,6,5,2,4,5,6,5,2,4,5,6,5,2,4,5,6],
    "eventname": ['hello','Free Kick','Pass','Pass','Shot','Interruption','Free Kick','Pass','Pass','Shot','Interruption','Free Kick','Pass','Pass','Shot','Interruption','Free Kick','Pass','Pass','Shot']
}
df=pd.DataFrame(data=dict)
print(tabulate(df, headers = 'keys', tablefmt = 'psql'))
```

Then slice the data and perform your task.

```
# Search for index values where "Shot" appear.
index_values = df[df['eventname'] == 'Shot'].index
# Add -1 at 0 index in index_value list
index_values = index_values.insert(0,-1)
#Slide the data. Over here you can perform your task on last four rows
for i in range(0,len(index_values)-1):
    # perform your task here
    print(tabulate(df[index_values[i]+1:index_values[i+1]], headers='keys', tablefmt='psql'))
```

Comment: Excellent thank you so much 